# How to pass the custom title, description and Image to google plus button like facebook share button

Tags: google-plus

I one of my project I am using the sharing buttons for multiple article. I need the link share urls for facebook, twitter and google plus.
To Facebook I can pass every parameter (title,image, description) to share URL. using following code

```
http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&amp;p[title]=<?php echo $title;?>&amp;p[summary]=<?php echo $summary;?>&amp;p[url]=<?php echo $url; ?>&amp;&p[images][0]=<?php echo $image;?>'
```

But For google plus I can pass only two parameters. (url and lang code). You can check the documentation here.
[google share link api](https://developers.google.com/+/web/share/)

Google itself crawl the webpage and take the title, description and image from webpage.

**Problem:**
I am loading content through javascript so when crawler came page web page. It is not able to collect the information.

Comment: Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10031065/google-share-with-custom-text-and-thumbnail?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

You can find answer for you question by visiting below url:

[Google+ share with custom text and thumbnail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10031065/google-share-with-custom-text-and-thumbnail)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the url you could do after 3 years

https://plus.google.com/share?url=http%3A//google.com