# Angular code show up when sharing on a social media

Tags: angularjs

I was going to share my site on google+ and realized that it displays my Angular code instead of my content, as such:

```
{{ item.time.end }}. {{ item.title }}. {{ item.company }}. {{ item.skill }}. 
{{ detail }}. {{ more }}. {{ item.time.start }}. Education: 
{{ item.course }}.{{ item.school }}. {{ item.subjects }}
```

I also noticed that when the page load, the code pops up for a half second before content gets rendered.

How could I fix these issues?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe because the Google+ bot that scan you website don't execute the angular.js code, so it renders only the HTML content of the page.

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak

Comment: For the second problem, it's because of the way AngularJS works. You'll probably want to use a spinner or a way to hide your content before it's completely loaded.

Comment: See [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10031065/google-share-with-custom-text-and-thumbnail) and the [snippet documentation](https://developers.google.com/+/web/snippet/). If you put in metadata to specify the correct snippets to use, hopefully it won't have to fetch your page raw.